# Should I prefer a const function?

Tags: c++, class, function, coding-style

Assume I want to implement class `A` which must load its "configuration" from a file. And let's assume the "configuration" is a simple `map<string, string>`.

I can implement the `A::LoadConfiguration` in two different ways:

1. `void A::LoadConfiguration(string filename)`
2. `map<string, string> A::LoadConfiguration(string filename) const`

Should I prefer either of the two implementations, and why?

Comment: you don't want to return the map, if it's a member of the class

Comment: Obviously, I'm assuming the map is part of the class. That's why the second implementation is a `const` function. I have seen developers who prefer the second implementation, but never got a concrete reason.

Comment: If `LoadConfiguration` does not modify the members of `A` then make it `const` otherwise don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer the second version when the user wants to get info on a file they will base all their algorithms on the map. If you do the second version, meaning the implementation may be a map, *but doesn't have to be*, they can base their code around an API which does not have to change even if the internal implementation does.

Consider the situation where later you realize it is far more efficient to use an std array, for whatever reason, now every program using this code has to change many of it's algorithms. Using the first version the change to array can be handled internally and reflect no changes on the outside.

Now if you are planning to make multiple instances of the class you will definitely want to make it a static method because you don't want the file to load every time you call the constructor (especially if the file will not change).

Answer (score 1):

Completely ignoring your suggestions, but this is probably how I would do it (not knowing all your constraints, so ignore me if it does not fit):

```
class A
{
public:
    static A fromConfiguration( string fileName );

    /* ... */
}
```

In most cases, the "configuration" of a class should be set at object creation, so forcing the user to provide it on construction is a good thing (instead of having to remember to do do the loading later).

```
namespace NeatStuff
{
    map<string,string> loadSimpleConfiguration( string fileName );
}
```

If the configuration file format is really simple (and not specific to your class) you can move the actual loading out of the class.

Comment: Thank you. Any reason for choosing a `static` function over a simple constructor?

Comment: You can think of it as a name for the constructor. Also imagine there might be multiple reasons for a constructor to take just a string (e.g. a name or a file to init from)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming other classes use the configuration later, I prefer option 1, and an additional `GetConfigurationParameter` public const method that gets the config value for a particular key. That lets me make other classes which can just ask for some parameter by name without ever caring that it's implemented as a map.

Another reason why I prefer option 1 is that loading a configuration should be distinct from returning it. If I see a name like `LoadConfiguration`, I assume that it loads the config from somewhere and sets the parameters in the class. I do not assume it returns some description of the configuration, which I'd instead expect from a method like `GetConfiguration` - but opinions on this will vary for different people of course.